# Invoke-RestMethod Range Error, Possible Bug?

Tags: json, powershell, api, webrequest

Example code that's generating error

```
$Headers = @{ 
"Token" = $Token; 
"Range" = $Range
}
                
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method GET -Headers $Headers -WebSession $WebSession
```

Error: `Invoke-RestMethod : The 'Range' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.`

I believe this is due to a [PowerShell Bug](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/security/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=2497&MessageKey=c5c2d4e6-f770-47ae-bc0b-d2bc102fd59b&CommunityKey=f9ea5420-0984-4345-ba7a-d93b4e2d4864&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2Fcommunity%2Fuser%2Fsecurity%2Fcommunities%2Fcommunity-home%2Fdigestviewer%3Fcommunitykey%3Df9ea5420-0984-4345-ba7a-d93b4e2d4864%26tab%3Ddigestviewer). So now I'm attempting with the below example code, and get generic 401 (not authorized) error.

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
$request.Method = "GET"
$request.Headers.Add("Token", $Token)
$request.AddRange("items", 0, 50)
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
$data = ConvertFrom-Json $reader.ReadToEnd()
```

The API requires a sessionId which I am clarifying in the first example code block. Is there a way to pass this in the above (second example code block)?

Any other reason for this 401 error? The first code block example retrieves data without issue if range isn't specified.

Comment: How are you creating your ```$WebSession``` variable in the first example? It's possible you already provided the authentication details in an earlier request and it's carrying a cookie over into ```Invoke-RestMethod``` via the web session, whereas your second example doesn't provide any authentication details.

Comment: You are correct, that is exactly what I am doing.  I am passing credentials (username/password) in order to create the websession. How would I go about creating credentials in the second code block?

I have tried adding 

`$request.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential('username','password')`

But still get 401 error.

Comment: If you edit your question to include the code that sets up the web session in the first example, someone might be able to help you translate it into the ```System.Net.WebRequest``` version. Don't include your *actual* username / password / auth tokens obviously!